# $MA(q)$ : Show $\sqrt{n}\hat{\rho}(q + l)\underrightarrow{d} N(0, 1 + 2\sum _{j=1}^q\rho ^2\left(j\right)), l\ge 1 $

Tags: normal-distribution, correlation, central-limit-theorem, time-series

$$\sqrt{n}\hat{\rho}(q + l)\underrightarrow{d}$$ $$N(0, 1 + 2\sum _{j=1}^q\rho ^2\left(j\right)), l\ge 1 $$

I am trying to show that for an $MA(q)$ process, the above holds. I'm having a hard time doing this. I'm not exactly sure how to start this off. I thought it might be similar to showing $$\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)\underrightarrow{d} N(0, \sum _{h=-\infty}^\infty\gamma_X\left(h\right))$$ but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried to show $$\sum _{h=-\infty}^\infty\rho\left(h\right) = 1 + 2\sum _{j=1}^q\rho ^2\left(j\right)$$ but this doesn't seem to work and I think it was a bad idea, which resulted in me wasting 5 pages and 4 hours, and still no breakthroughs on how to solve the problem.

I think it might be a Bartlett's Formula problem, but I'm not sure how to apply it here.

Any help would be appreciated. This problem is on time series and the textbook being used in class can be found [here](http://home.iitj.ac.in/%7Eparmod/document/introduction%20time%20series.pdf).

I have an exam coming up and I really want to be able to understand this problem and how to solve it. Please help!

Thank you

Comment: `\sqrt{n}`, not `\sqrt(n)`

Comment: Fix the subject line too, if you would.

Comment: Can't just fix it in full, huh?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sorry about that, it's been a long day